# Integrating Paypal with Phalcon 3

Tags: paypal, phalcon

I want to integrate paypal in my Phalcon 3 web application. It would be great if anyone could help me in this process.

After doing a google search; I came across these resource: https://github.com/MiladAlshomary/paypal_phalcon and https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

To be specific, I was looking for an example/tutorial where it shows me how to integrate paypal in phalcon 3.

As requested here is how my code looks like:

My config.php looks like this:

```
"paypal" => [
    "apiUsername" =>"xxxx",
    "apiPassword" =>"xxxxx",
    "apiSignature" =>"",
    "apiLive" => "false",
    "returnUrl" => "http://paypal/confirm/",
    "cancelUrl" => "http://paypal/cancel/",
    "payment_description" => "Purchasing with paypal",
    "payment_amount" => 50
    ],
```

xxxx is replaced by my sandbox credentials. And I am using the buyAction from controller with these changes.

```
$config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Php(__DIR__ . '/../../app/config/config.php');
```

I have included the library in index.php located in public folder and the code goes like this: `include DIR . "/../library/Paypal.php";`

Comment: Have you tried implementing the first library? **If yes**: post your code and show us what errors your are getting. **If no**: implement the library yourself. Then refer to the previous point

Comment: @Timothy I have integrated the API using instructions from https://github.com/MiladAlshomary/paypal_phalcon. However I am getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the paypal API at https://developer.paypal.com/ gave me insight about how to approach this problem.

If you have any alternative solutions then please feel free to share them with me.